# Own Localization Provider or build on top of the ResourceProvider in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, localization

To use the built in Localization (Resource Provider) in ASP.NET can only handle translated strings (see GetString("key", locale) with no user defined arguments if I have read the documentation correct.

What is the best, to build a custom resource provider that can handle arguments like GetString("key", locale, parameters)? To use that, I change the API which not is to good because the ResourceProvider always should be the same out to the developer and the only thing that can/should be different is the backend.

The second alternative I see is to build new provider that derives from ProviderBase or maybe to make a class that not derives from anything.

What do you think? Should I add methods to the Resource Provider or build something new?

Answer (score 1):

You could:

a)  store the localized strings with placeholders, either {0}, {1},..., {n} which will then work with string.Format() or

b) use your own placeholders ({FirstName}, {LastName}, {JobTitle}, etc.) and then replace them in your own methods with actual values. Translators can move the placeholders around (because sentences are built differently based on the language).

I am not sure what you want the parameters for, but I guess it's about the scenario in b) above.